# Unable to get any kind of audio from I2S INMP441 omnidirectional microphone on ESP32 devboard

Tags: arduino, esp32, microphone, i2s, mems-microphone

I am trying to get an I2S INMP441 omnidirectional microphone module to interface with an ESP32 devboard.  I have been unable to get any kind of information from it. I have tried multiple ESP32s and two separate microphones with no luck.

I used the following example code:

```
    #include <driver/i2s.h>
    
    // you shouldn't need to change these settings
    #define SAMPLE_BUFFER_SIZE 512
    #define SAMPLE_RATE 8000
    // most microphones will probably default to left channel but you may need to tie the L/R pin low
    #define I2S_MIC_CHANNEL I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_ONLY_LEFT
    // either wire your microphone to the same pins or change these to match your wiring
    #define I2S_MIC_SERIAL_CLOCK 32
    #define I2S_MIC_LEFT_RIGHT_CLOCK 25
    #define I2S_MIC_SERIAL_DATA 33
    
    // don't mess around with this
    i2s_config_t i2s_config = {
        .mode = (i2s_mode_t)(I2S_MODE_MASTER | I2S_MODE_RX),
        .sample_rate = SAMPLE_RATE,
        .bits_per_sample = I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_32BIT,
        .channel_format = I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_ONLY_LEFT,
        .communication_format = I2S_COMM_FORMAT_I2S,
        .intr_alloc_flags = ESP_INTR_FLAG_LEVEL1,
        .dma_buf_count = 4,
        .dma_buf_len = 1024,
        .use_apll = false,
        .tx_desc_auto_clear = false,
        .fixed_mclk = 0};
    
    // and don't mess around with this
    i2s_pin_config_t i2s_mic_pins = {
        .bck_io_num = I2S_MIC_SERIAL_CLOCK,
        .ws_io_num = I2S_MIC_LEFT_RIGHT_CLOCK,
        .data_out_num = I2S_PIN_NO_CHANGE,
        .data_in_num = I2S_MIC_SERIAL_DATA};
    
    void setup()
    {
      // we need serial output for the plotter
      Serial.begin(115200);
      // start up the I2S peripheral
      i2s_driver_install(I2S_NUM_0, &i2s_config, 0, NULL);
      i2s_set_pin(I2S_NUM_0, &i2s_mic_pins);
    }
    
    int32_t raw_samples[SAMPLE_BUFFER_SIZE];
    void loop()
    {
      // read from the I2S device
      size_t bytes_read = 0;
      i2s_read(I2S_NUM_0, raw_samples, sizeof(int32_t) * SAMPLE_BUFFER_SIZE, &bytes_read, portMAX_DELAY);
      int samples_read = bytes_read / sizeof(int32_t);
      // dump the samples out to the serial channel.
      for (int i = 0; i < samples_read; i++)
      {
        Serial.printf("%ld\n", raw_samples[i]);
      }
    }
```

I have also tried [this example](https://diyi0t.com/i2s-sound-tutorial-for-esp32/).

[Microphone Module](https://www.amazon.ca/DAOKI-Omnidirectional-Microphone-Interface-Precision/dp/B0821521CV/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?keywords=I2S%20microphone%20daoki&qid=1664836534&qu=eyJxc2MiOiIxLjczIiwicXNhIjoiMC4wMCIsInFzcCI6IjAuMDAifQ%3D%3D&sr=8-1-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEzRTJYNlVITFQ0WlM3JmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwMDI3MjU2M1QxU1JBU0daMkpUTyZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwODY4MDMyMjRVV0tYOE8xNFU1UyZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX2F0ZiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU=)

I am not quite sure if I just received duds or if I am doing something wrong.

**SOLVED!**
There is a bug with espressif causing the channels to be inversed. Right is left and left is right. Replace the following line
`.channel_format = I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_ONLY_LEFT,`
With
`.channel_format = I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_ONLY_RIGHT,`

Comment: in general how are you debugging your platform? do you have something liek a debug UARt output where you can insert printf statements? or are you using a debugger? To break it down. you might first just try to see that the device driver is initialised. Then see whether reading the device is possible and gives some sensible data. It is entirely normal for an embedded component NOT to work on first try, until a bit of debugging and so on has been done. Always try to build your system in small, verifiable steps, one step at a time. Throwing together a complex example rarely works first try.

Comment: What are the values you receive from the printf output?

Comment: @Jens, Serial monitor only reports 0, but when checked with an oscilloscope, there is still a PWM signal which is non-recurring. Could it be that the esp32 is somehow incapable of parsing the information? How might I read the raw data?

Comment: @grabt234 gives a reasonable answer, probably this could be your solution. Also with idf5 I run into some i2s quirks. At the end it works. On github you will find more comparable issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using IDF V4.4.3 there appears to be a bug with regards to the left and right channel selection. It is described [here](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/issues/6625). Changing the channel format addressed the all 0's issue for me.

Comment: Thank you! You were correct. The channels are indeed inversed. Changed .channel_format from I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_ONLY_LEFT to I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_ONLY_RIGHT,